# Laravel Octane cache driver issue

Tags: laravel, caching

I've an issue with cache using octane cache driver with Laravel.

This works with 10 users stored in the cache :

```
$users = Cache::store('octane')->rememberForever('users', function () {
        return User::select('name')->take(10)->get();
    });
```

But if I replace ->take(10) by ->take(100) this errors appears :
[image]

I tried to modify the config/octane.php file, but it doesn't change anything.
Thank's for help.

Comment: After you increase the `octane.cache.bytes` from the default 10000 value to something more reasonable for your use case, you need to also clear you cache since previously cached values are not affected